# Selecting drop down option using XPath & C# for an HTML table

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, visual-studio-2013, selenium-webdriver

I want to choose a specific selection in this table, my table & specific selection being:

```
<table border="0" align="CENTER">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="FieldLabel" valign="top" nowrap="" colspan="1">
                <td valign="top" nowrap="" colspan="3">
                <select class="HandleSelectChange" name="DISPLAY_RequestingProvider" style="width:100%;" size="1">
                    <option selected="" value="">Choose One</option>
                    <option value="1134303902NMDX0NMDX0 NMDX0Company Name">Company Name - 1234567890</option>
                </select>
                </td>
           </tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

There are about 25 selections in this table, which is why I only included one of them.

Currently, my code can not find the element. My current code is as follows:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[td[contains(text(),'Company Name')]]/td[2]")).Click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate the `select` element and use `SelectElement` object to select an option by text:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[.//option = 'Company Name')]]//select[@name = 'DISPLAY_RequestingProvider']")).Click()

SelectElement selector = new SelectElement(element);
selector.SelectByText("Company Name");
```